# Problem with 3D plot in Animate ( Plot not showing)

Tags: plotting, animation

I was trying to implement Schrödinger equation for free particle. I have plotted probability density for a single value of time, that plot is showing. But, when I am trying to animate over time, plot is showing empty.

```
eqn = {I D[\[Psi][x, y, t], t] == - ((\[HBar]^2  \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(\[Psi][x, y, 
        t]\)\))/(2 m))};
initcond = {\[Psi][x, y, 
     0] == \[Sqrt]2  (Sin[2 \[Pi] x] Sin[\[Pi] y] + 
       Sin[\[Pi] x] Sin[3 \[Pi] y])};
bcs = {\[Psi][0, y, t] == 0, \[Psi][1, y, t] == 0, \[Psi][x, 1, t] == 
    0 , \[Psi][x, 0, t] == 0 };
sol = DSolveValue[{eqn, bcs, initcond}, \[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y, t}]
p[x_, y_, t_] := 
  ComplexExpand[sol Conjugate[sol]] /. {m -> 1, xMax -> 1, 
    yMax -> 1, \[HBar]^2 -> 1 };
Plot3D[p[x, y, t] /. t -> 0.5, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u(x,t)"}, PlotRange -> All]
Animate[Plot3D[p[x, y, t] /. t -> t, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "p(x,y,t)"}, PlotRange ->All, 
  Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, 2, 0.1}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Please help.

Comment: One problem is  `t -> t`, which is non-syntactic.  Strong recommendation:  simplify your problem by eliminating useless junk, like all the definitions of terms = 1, labels, and such.

Comment: Start MMA fresh with an empty notebook. Scrape your block of code above and paste it into the empty notebook. Tap <shift><Enter> and see if you get the same error that I do and if so whether you can fix that. Thanks

Comment: In the definition of `p`, change SetDelayed (:=) to Set (=)

Comment: Or `p[x_, y_, t_] := 
    ComplexExpand[sol Conjugate[sol]] /. {m -> 1, xMax -> 1, 
         yMax -> 1, ℏ^2 -> 1 } // Evaluate;`

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks. Problem solved.